# Scrapy on M1 Mac: MemoryError: Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback()

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to scrapy, and recently started using it on the M1 MacBook Air. I've encountered an issue.

For example, when I try to do something like this:

```
scrapy shell bbc.com
```

It would return me: **MemoryError: Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback(). You might be running on a system that prevents this. For more information, see https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#callbacks**

It is worth noting that if I do the exact same thing on Windows, everything works. Also, when I use scrapy shell on websites like http://quotes.toscrape.com/ or HTTP websites on the M1 Mac, it also works. Seems like a HTTPS issue but I'm really not sure.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you found any solution?

Answer (score 5):

```bash
conda uninstall --force cffi
pip install cffi
```

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/1205

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is just to upgrade requests module

```
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this for a few months. For me, it seem to be a problem with pyopenssl. I have not found a solution.

If you try with an `http` website (instead of `https`), you may find that it works: `scrapy shell http://httpforever.com`

Relevant issue: https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/873

Additional conversation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16907

Update 20211129:

HTTPS sites such as `scrapy shell https://www.bbc.com` are working for me again. My environment:

- M1 Macbook Pro
- MacOS 12.0.1
- Python 3.10.0
- Scrapy==2.5.1

Comment: The problems seems to be in pyOpenSSL, which is fixed with Python 3.10. I got it also working on my Macbook Pro with M1.

Comment: I've got this working on an M1 with python 3.9.6 but I'm getting the `ffi.callback()` error on an M1 with 3.10.4. Both are running pyopenssl 22.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

If your scrapy version is 2.7.1, Python Version is lower and also you use anaconda,I propose you can update Python Version to 3.10,I solved the problem by this way

Answer (score 0):

I also met this issue yesterday. What I did was create a virtual environment with python 3.10.4.

```
conda create -n scrapyPy310 python==3.10.4
source activate scrapyPy310
pip install scrapy
scrapy shell www.bbc.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this issue when I install `scrapy` using `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`.

However, when I install it using `pip`, it works for me.

```bash
conda create -n scrapy python=3.10
conda activate scrapy
pip install scrapy

scrapy shell https://bbc.com
```

Here is my packages:

```
(scrapy) √ ~ % conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/x/anaconda3/envs/scrapy:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
attrs                     22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
automat                   22.10.0                  pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h620ffc9_4
ca-certificates           2022.10.11           hca03da5_0
certifi                   2022.9.24       py310hca03da5_0
cffi                      1.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
constantly                15.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              38.0.3                   pypi_0    pypi
cssselect                 1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hyperlink                 21.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
incremental               22.10.0                  pypi_0    pypi
itemadapter               0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
itemloaders               1.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
jmespath                  1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    14.0.6               h848a8c0_0
libffi                    3.4.2                hc377ac9_4
lxml                      4.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.3                  h1a28f6b_3
openssl                   1.1.1s               h1a28f6b_0
packaging                 21.3                     pypi_0    pypi
parsel                    1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.2.2          py310hca03da5_0
protego                   0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21                     pypi_0    pypi
pydispatcher              2.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.6               hbdb9e5c_1
queuelib                  1.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0
requests                  2.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-file             1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
scrapy                    2.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
service-identity          21.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                65.5.0          py310hca03da5_0
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.39.3               h1058600_0
tk                        8.6.12               hb8d0fd4_0
tldextract                3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
twisted                   22.10.0                  pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2022f                h04d1e81_0
urllib3                   1.26.12                  pypi_0    pypi
w3lib                     2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
xz                        5.2.6                h1a28f6b_0
zlib                      1.2.13               h5a0b063_0
zope-interface            5.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Answer (score -1):

install cffi on conda environment

```
conda install cffi
```