# Can't use scrapy on Apple M1 chip

Tags: python, scrapy, apple-m1

I have a basic code that aim to scrap 'quotes.com' and retrieve the titles of two pages, using scrapy library:

```py
import scrapy

class Crawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        "https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/",
        "https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.css("title::text").get())
```

On my Apple Macbook Pro (M1 Pro chip), it gives me a 'MemoryError':

```bash
MemoryError: Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback(). 
You might be running on a system that prevents this.
For more information, see https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#callbacks
```

What can I do to make it work ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy on M1 Mac: MemoryError: Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556847/scrapy-on-m1-mac-memoryerror-cannot-allocate-writeexecute-memory-for-ffi-call)

Answer (score 0):

Using a Python 3.10 environment did the trick for me.